# Material date picker is not working within ion-modal

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5, angular11

The below is not working when we call the material date picker in a ion-modal popup.

In the main page, i have this code to open the modalcontroller.

```
const modal = await this.modalController.create({
  component: TestPage,
  cssClass: 'my-custom-modal-css1',
  swipeToClose: true,
  // breakpoints: [0, 0.2, 0.5, 1],
  // initialBreakpoint: 0.2,
  presentingElement: await this.modalController.getTop(),
});

return await modal.present();
```

```
In the TestPage, i have included this html

      <mat-card class="demo-inline-calendar-card">
      <mat-calendar [(selected)]="selected"></mat-calendar>
    </mat-card>
    <p>Selected date: {{selected}}</p>
```

It is not working in Testpage but it is working in the main page.

There is no solution to fix this..

Solution:

I have fixed the mat-calendar display issue.
I have imported the module but it needs to declare the component ts in app module like below:

```
  declarations: [TestPage], 
  entryComponents: [TestPage],
```

Once including it, the calendar inline shown in the modal.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: why are you using Material UI in ionic?

Comment: while what @NajamUsSaqib said is true, but mostly when u open pickers from ion modals, then u need to import mat calender inside app module instead of the launching page module (so the import should be global in order to be used inside a modal)

Comment: @MostafaHarb I have imported the mat calendar in app module too but its not working. But when i use input type=date it is working. But none of the material calendar or custom calendar not working

Comment: @MostafaHarb I have fixed the mat-calendar display issue after a day. 
I have imported the module but it needs to declare the component ts in app moduleas like below: 
 @NgModule({
  declarations: [TestPage], 
  entryComponents: [TestPage],